# Fullcalendar overlaps dropdown list

Tags: fullcalendar

I implemented the Fullcalendar API.
Now, when I select one of my items in the header, Fullcalendar always overlaps the dropdown entries.

So it looks like:

[image]

As we can see the middle entry is being overlapped.
I already tried to adapt full calendar`s CSS in Eclipse but I canont adapt the jar file.
Everything is imported via Maven, maybe that is the reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the fullcalendar. The dropdown content is not displayed in the foreground. In my index.css I use dropdown-content-admin, maybe I can add something like z-index that will solve the problem ( currently it does not work! ).

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.
The solution is to use z-index in my index.css.

I set it to

```
z-index: 10000;
```

only to be sure.

Now, the dropdown menue is always in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the FullCalendar's parent to `z-index: 0`;

It does not really matter if it is in inline-style or in `index.css, main.css, tailwind, bootstrap`..

There's more, even if you set the dropdown AND the FullCalendar `z-index` to 0, the component/tag you are interacting with will overlap first. So I won't be any issues!